# 405 and 500 errors when creating GeoTIFF layers by GeoServer REST API

Tags: geoserver, geoserver-rest-api

I have created a coverage store in GeoServer using the REST API.

http://localhost:8010/geoserver/rest/workspaces/sdwdrnTif_Test/coveragestores?configure=all

```xml
<coverageStore>
        <name>postman-seonyudo</name>
        <workspace>sdwdrnTif_Test</workspace>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <type>GeoTIFF</type>
        <url>file:test_TIFF/seonyudo.tif</url>
</coverageStore>
```

Coverage store has been successfully created, so i wanted to publish a WMS layer for the coverage store.

I tried these : 1. http://localhost:8010/geoserver/rest/workspaces/sdwdrnTif_Test/coveragestores/postman-seonyudo/coverages

```xml
<coverages>
    <coverage>
        <name>seonyudo</name>
    </coverage>
</coverages>
```

it returned 500 error.

2. http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/sdwdrnTif_Test/coveragestores/seonyudoTEST/external.geotiff?configure=first&coverageName=seonyudoTEST

   ```
   file://C:\tif\seonyudo2.tif
   ```

And it gave me a 405 err code with this message:

> "Error 405 Coverage store found, but it does not support resource
> harvesting."

Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong? How can I create a layer for this store using GeoServer REST API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your POST body is wrong in the first case, when in doubt make a GET request of an existing object to see what the expected format is.

So for example `http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/nurc/coveragestores/worldImageSample/coverages/Img_Sample.xml` returns:

```
<coverage>
  <name>Img_Sample</name>
  <nativeName>Img_Sample</nativeName>
  <namespace>
    <name>nurc</name>
    <atom:link xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" rel="alternate" href="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/namespaces/nurc.xml" type="application/xml"/>
  </namespace>
  <title>North America sample imagery</title>
  <description>A very rough imagery of North America</description>
  <keywords>
    <string>WCS</string>
    <string>worldImageSample</string>
    <string>worldImageSample_Coverage</string>
  </keywords>
  <nativeCRS>GEOGCS[&quot;WGS 84&quot;, 
  DATUM[&quot;WGS_1984&quot;, 
    SPHEROID[&quot;WGS 84&quot;, 6378137.0, 298.257223563, AUTHORITY[&quot;EPSG&quot;,&quot;7030&quot;]], 
    AUTHORITY[&quot;EPSG&quot;,&quot;6326&quot;]], 
  PRIMEM[&quot;Greenwich&quot;, 0.0, AUTHORITY[&quot;EPSG&quot;,&quot;8901&quot;]], 
  UNIT[&quot;degree&quot;, 0.017453292519943295], 
  AXIS[&quot;Longitude&quot;, EAST], 
  AXIS[&quot;Latitude&quot;, NORTH], 
  AUTHORITY[&quot;EPSG&quot;,&quot;4326&quot;]]</nativeCRS>
  <srs>EPSG:4326</srs>
  <nativeBoundingBox>
    <minx>-130.85168</minx>
    <maxx>-62.0054</maxx>
    <miny>20.7052</miny>
    <maxy>54.1141</maxy>
    <crs>EPSG:4326</crs>
  </nativeBoundingBox>
  <latLonBoundingBox>
    <minx>-130.85168</minx>
    <maxx>-62.0054</maxx>
    <miny>20.7052</miny>
    <maxy>54.1141</maxy>
    <crs>EPSG:4326</crs>
  </latLonBoundingBox>
  <enabled>true</enabled>
  ....
<requestSRS>
    <string>EPSG:4326</string>
  </requestSRS>
  <responseSRS>
    <string>EPSG:4326</string>
  </responseSRS>
</coverage>
```

so your post body should be (at least):

```
<coverage>
    <name>seonyudo</name>
</coverage>
```

and might need other values too, see the [manual page](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/api/#1.0.0/coverages.yaml) for more details.

Comment: Thank you ! I donated a coffee